# A blocking, interactive plot in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to get an interactive, blocking matplotlib window out of Jupyter notebook. That is, I want the matplotlib window to come up and for execution in the notebook to pause until it closes. But various, reasonable-seeming permutations of my code don't seem to work.

The following produces the expected result:

```
%matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]

plt.figure()
plt.plot(a,b)
plt.show(block=True)
print("hi")
```

But *only once*. If the code is run the second time, the kernel seems to lock up and I have to restart it, which is a no-go for my application.

The following alternatives produce an interactive window, but the code proceeds directly to the print statement without waiting for the window to be closed:

```
%matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]

plt.figure()
plt.plot(a,b)
plt.show()
print("hi")
```

I get the same result from:

```
%matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]

plt.figure()
plt.plot(a,b)
plt.ioff()
plt.show()
print("hi")
```

and

```
%matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]

plt.figure()
plt.plot(a,b)
plt.ion()
plt.show()
print("hi")
```

How can I accomplish this goal? (The goal being to have `print("hi")` not execute until after the interactive matplotlib window closes.)

(I'm using Python 3.5.3 and Jupyter notebook server 5.0.0.)

Comment: Interesting question. Although there might not be any magic command that allows for blocking within the cell. Is there any special reason you need this? I would imagine that placing the code in the next cell is how people usually do this kind of workflow.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: An interactive matplotlib window is used to get user input (boundaries of a region of interest) which influences the rest of the analysis. It is preferable to have this all happen in the same cell so that I can loop over several inputs.

Comment: What kind of input is this? Usually you would use events and callbacks to manage such things? (I would agree that this sounds not as appealing, because of a lot of additional code needed, but it might be the only option here.)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: I define a class in a cell at the top of the program (or, once the code is stable, import said class as a library). The class both attempts to display the matplotlib window interactively and collects user input via mouseclicks and keyboard presses via callbacks. The problem is that the interactive matplotlib window either does not block or the kernel freezes up when blocking is used, as described in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you cannot block the execution of a cell in the middle. However the usecase described in the comments seems to allow to process everything within the event loop of the figure itself.

```
# cell 1:
%matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class InterAct():
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.ax.axis([0,1,0,1])
        self.ax.set_title("Click to choose points, close to proceed")
        self.plot, = self.ax.plot([],[], color="crimson", ls="", marker="o")
        self.points = []
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event", self.select_point)
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect("close_event", self.process)
        plt.show()

    def select_point(self, event):
        self.points.append((event.xdata,event.ydata))
        x,y = list(zip(*self.points))
        self.plot.set_data(x,y)
        self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()

    def process(self, event):
        points = np.array(self.points)
        mean = points.mean(axis=0)
        r = np.sqrt(np.sum((points-mean)**2, axis=1)).max()

        self.fig2, self.ax2 = plt.subplots()
        self.ax2.axis([0,1,0,1])
        self.ax2.set_title("The result is:")
        poly = plt.Polygon(points, edgecolor="C0", fill=True, alpha=0.5)
        circ = plt.Circle(mean, r, color="crimson", fill=False)
        self.ax2.add_patch(circ)
        self.ax2.add_patch(poly)

        self.fig2.show()
        #plt.show()
```

And then

```
# cell 2
i = InterAct()
```

This would first show a matplotlib figure, where the user can interactively do something (in this case click to select points). Then when the user closes the figure, the points are processed and a new figure with the result is shown.

Comment: This is nice, thank you. I'll leave the question open a little longer, and if nothing solving it specifically comes in, accept this answer. Feel free to remind me if I forget. (I've set a timer for a month out.)

Answer (score 2):

In case anybody looks for "blocking execution" until window is closed, here is a simple solution. Put this code in a cell.

```
# Provided the backend is interactive
# e.g. %matplotlib qt5
fig = plt.figure()
plt.show()

try:
    while fig.number in plt.get_fignums():
        plt.pause(0.1)
except:
    plt.close(fig.number)
    raise

print("hi!")
```

The loop in this snippet waits until the current figure is in the list of active figures. When a user closes the figure's window, its number disappears from the list returned by `plt.get_fignums()`.

To make the cell interruptable the snippet catches exceptions. When the user stops the cell by *Interrupt the kernel* (aka Stop) button then `KeyboardInterrupt` error is injected into the Python event loop. The snippet catches it and closes the figure `fig`.

The duration in `plt.pause` defines delay in the script reaction. The bigger this value is, the longer is the delay between closing the window and printing `hi!`

The cell could be re-executed any number of times.

Comment: This is nice! But when there is more than one figure, all the figures blinks in a very annoying way. Can that be fixed in some way?