# Event handling and picking does not work with Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

When I run the following script in a `IPython (IPython 8.2.0)` console opened from `Anaconda powershell` I am allowed to pick points from the figure.
Then, the script continues only once I close the figure, as it should be.

However, when I run the same script on `Spyder` this won't happen: the script won't allow me to pick any point from the figure but it continues straight to the end, thus always resulting in printing `tin = 0` and `tout = 0` and returning the `IPython` prompt.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2)

ax[0, 0].plot(np.random.rand(10))
ax[0, 1].plot(np.random.rand(10))
ax[1, 0].plot(np.random.rand(10))
ax[1, 1].plot(np.random.rand(10))


def onclick(event):
    if onclick.index == 0:
        onclick.tin = np.round(event.xdata, 3)
    else:
        onclick.tout = np.round(event.xdata, 3)
    print('tin = ', onclick.tin, 'tout =', onclick.tout, end='\r')
    onclick.index = (onclick.index+1) % 2


onclick.index = 0
onclick.tin = 0
onclick.tout = 0

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.show()
fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)
tin = onclick.tin
tout = onclick.tout
print('\n\n tin = ', tin, 'tout =', tout, end='\r')
```

I am running the following version of Spyder:

- Spyder version: 5.1.5 None
- Python version: 3.9.12 64-bit
- Qt version: 5.9.7
- PyQt5 version: 5.9.2
- Operating System: Windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this:

1. You can change your `plt.show()` call to

   ```
   plt.show(block=True)
   ```

   However, after closing the figure, you need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> in the console to get the prompt back on it.
2. You can add the code in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68274737/438386) just below `plt.show()`. The advantage of that is that you'll get the prompt back after closing the figure.

Comment: Thanks. I did as you suggest but the only effect I had was either to have inline plot or to have the plots in the Plots pane. You can copy paste the code and run it both on Spyder and on a IPython console :)

Comment: Sorry, that was the old way of doing things but it doesn't work anymore (I should have checked before posting). However, I found a way that works, so I'll rewrite my answer. Actually, you don't need to change anything in Spyder.

Comment: Thanks! It would be nice if in the solution 1 the user is not forced to hit Ctrl+c to get the prompt back, but it happens automatically. Maybe something to fix for the next Spyder release? ;)

Comment: I think that's something we could solve in Spyder, sorry.

Comment: you mean you couldn't? :)

Comment: Right, sorry, I meant we couldn't solve this in Spyder.

Comment: Hello! I am using the method 2. but when I have two figures opened they blink annoyingly. Apparently, the blinking period is the same specified in the `plt.pause(0.1)` command. This won't happen when I have only one figure opened. Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.